# Determine the nature of this logarithmic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  k*\ln(1-\frac{1}{k})$$
Can you apply the Raabe test for this series?I have looked at the other tests for convergence or divergence but they didn't look the same like the Raabe.

Comment: Just take the limit of the sequence, it is not $0$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I know the answer to the limit is -1.Does that mean it diverges?

Comment: Of course it does. Adding up infinitely many things can only make sense if we eventually stop adding, i.e. keep adding $0$'s.

Comment: Did you compute some partial sums to get an idea about the behavior? Btw, the term is undefined for $k=1$.

Comment: @MartinR No,I just calculated the series with the limit to infinity.

Comment: As others have implied, this series diverges by the divergence test (since $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \ne 0$).

Answer (score 0):

We have that since as $x \to 0 \implies \log(1+x) \sim x$

$$k\cdot\ln(1-\frac{1}{k}) \sim k\cdot \left(-\frac1k\right)=-1 $$

therefore the series diverges.